# how access the radio group value in jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery

how to access the radio group option and pass into ajax data array

```
<input type="radio" name="Comment[rating]" value="good">Good
<input type="radio" name="Comment[rating]" value="bad">Bad

$.ajax({
  url: '_rating_save.php',
  data: {productID:id,
         rating:$('input[name="Comment[rating]"]:checked').val()
  },
});
```

Comment: I have checked your code, it is working fine. please find in fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4dNCj/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need escape `[` like meta characters

```
 rating:$('input[name="Comment\\[rating\\]"]:checked').val()
```

[**DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dNCj/)